# Could detergents dissolve cell membranes?

Tags: lipids

Animal cells have a lipid membrane and detergents are great at emulsifying lipids. Yes, there are proteins, cholesterol and other numerous substances in the lipid bilayer, but the lipids make up the majority of it. If we dipped a bacterium or an isolated animal cell in detergent, would their membrane be dissolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they can dissolve membranes and are even used to isolate active forms of membrane proteins by solubilization. The product are micelles of a lipid-detergent mix and a protein-lipid-detergent complex. Maybe you find this short abstract interesting.

> A critical step in any in vitro analysis of membrane proteins is the
>   solubilization of the membrane to extract the protein of interest in
>   an active form to obtain an aqueous solution containing the membrane
>   protein complexed with detergents and lipids in a form suitable for
>   purification and further analysis. This process is particularly
>   delicate as the aim is to maximally disrupt the lipid components of
>   the membrane while putting the protein components in an un-natural
>   detergent environment without perturbing them. Looked at this way, it
>   is remarkable that it ever works. Although the process is difficult
>   and hard to master, an increasing number of membrane proteins have
>   been successfully solubilized in active forms, allowing some general
>   principles to be established that we illustrate in the method
>   developed in this chapter.

Duquesne K., Sturgis J.N. (2010) Membrane Protein Solubilization. In: Mus-Veteau I. (eds) Heterologous Expression of Membrane Proteins. Methods in Molecular Biology™ (Methods and Protocols), vol 601. Humana Press

Comment: So if our skin wasn't protected by the keratin layers, it would dissolve with detergents as well? What about GI epithelia?